# culture for datetime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Hi all I have written a code to parse datetime as follows

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString(), out _dtVoucherDate))
    _dtVoucherDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString());
else
    _dtVoucherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Which works fine in my system as my current datetime format is `MM/DD/YYYY` , but in my colleague system the datetime format is different `15 June 2013` so my code fails there. How can I convert the date to a universal format irrespective of the system date or some other

Comment: If the type of the column in the `DataTable` is already `DateTime` don't convert it to `string` and then  back to `DateTime`. Instead use the strongly typed [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) extension method: `dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date")`

Comment: Whatever you do, don't make the mistake of parsing the date in one format and then trying in a different format if the first one fails. That would be very bad because dates with day numbers 12 or less will become ambiguous wrt dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy formats.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to handle all formats, but you can speicify multiple allowed formats for `ParseExact`:

```
var str = dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<String>("Date");
var allowedFormats = new[] { "MM-dd-yyyy", "dd MMM yyyy" };
_dtVoucherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(str, allowedFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

**Note**: If the type of the column in the `DataTable` is already `DateTime` don't convert it to `string` and then back to `DateTime`. Instead use the strongly typed [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method:

```
dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString(), 
    "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, out _dtVoucherDate))
//the rest of it
```

Comment: This is not the format OP is using in his `ParseExact` approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Whoops, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First parse Datetime with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dsVchRecord.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

then Get Current Culture

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

then pass DateTime Object into current culture

```
dt = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString(cultureInfo))
```

Comment: Do you mean parse first with the invariant culture, then if that fails try and parse it with the current culture?